# AngularJS: Change hash and route without completely reloading controller

Tags: controller, reload, routes, angularjs, persist

I have a controller, with a route like this:

#/articles/1234

I want to change the route without completely reloading the controller, so I can keep the position of other stuff in the controller constant (lists that scroll)

I can think of a few ways to do this, but they're all pretty ugly. Is there a best practice for doing something like this? I tried experimenting with reloadOnSearch: false, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 34):

Had the very same challange,

Found a hack in [another StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429133/682267) that did the trick

Fairly clean solution - all I did was to add these lines to the controller that sets $location.path:

```
var lastRoute = $route.current;
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    $route.current = lastRoute;
});
```

..and made sure $route in injected into the controller of course.

But still, feels like "DoNotFollowRoutesOnPathChange" is a missing feature in AngularJS.

/Jens

**Update:** Since listening to this event effectively kills further usage of $routeProvider configs, I had to limit this catch to current path only:

```
    var lastRoute = $route.current;
    if ($route.current.$route.templateUrl.indexOf('mycurrentpath') > 0) {
        $route.current = lastRoute;         
    }
```

Getting ugly...

Comment: I used this setup for something I'm working on, I think you're better off listening for $route.current.$$route.controller, ie
  

`$route.current.$$route.controller == 'controllerName'`

That's a little more reliable than playing path games.

Comment: After trying to get this to work in my project, I settled on listening for `$route.current.params.reload == 'false'` where I cause the $location change to happen with something like `$location.url('/...?reload=false');`.  That way it's explicit, and there's no weird errors if the templateUrl or the controller happen to be the same on another route.

Comment: This really should be configurable from within the framework.

Comment: @MalucoMarinero `$$route.controller` doesn't exist anymore, at least as of 1.4.8.

Answer (score 21):

### Brief Answer:

You can use the `$location.search()` method as you mentioned. You should listen to the `"$routeUpdate"` event on scope instead of other route events. [$route API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

### Explanation:

1. First of all (you already know), add `reloadOnSearch: false` to your `$routeProvider`:

   ```js
   $routeProvider.when('/somewhere', {
       controller: 'SomeCtrl',
       reloadOnSearch: false
   })
   ```
2. Change your anchor tag `href` or `ng-href` to `href="#/somewhere?param=value"` this will trigger `$routeChangeSuccess` event if the path part (`/somewhere`) is not the same as current location. Otherwise it will trigger `$routeUpdate` event.
3. Listen event on scope:

   ```js
   $scope.$on("$routeUpdate", function(event, route) {
       // some code here
   });
   ```
4. If you want to change search params in code, you can use `$location.search()` method. [$location.search API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search).

Comment: After spending a couple of days researching and trying different approaches, I came across your answer. Worked like a charm using the normal AngularJS router, which was important to us. Verified using AngularJS v1.3.12 on Windows/MAC/iOS mobile, tablets, and PCs.

Answer (score 8):

If you set reloadOnSearch to false, you can set the `?a=b&c=d` portion of the url without reload.  You can't change the actual location prettily, though, without a reload.

Comment: I can change the query parameters without reloading the whole page? As in, before the hash? Or do you mean if I have the ?a=b&c=d at the end, after the hash?

Comment: Yeah, you can change the query parameters with `$location.search('a','b');`

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if that's ideal for this app, I'd rather stay consistent with the hash being the definitive route.

I was considering having a controller that would be the route's path, which would send events to show and hide the actual controller, and only fully update it if it's being loaded for the first time. That sounds pretty ugly though, so I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

## Edit

Better approach when using ngRoute:

```
/**
 * Add skipReload() to $location service.
 *
 * See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699
 */
app.factory('location',
  ['$rootScope', '$route', '$location',
  function($rootScope, $route, $location) {

  $location.skipReload = function() {
    var lastRoute = $route.current;

    var deregister = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',
                                    function(e, absUrl, oldUrl) {
      console.log('location.skipReload', 'absUrl:', absUrl, 'oldUrl:', oldUrl);
      $route.current = lastRoute;
      deregister();
    });

    return $location;
  };

  return $location;
}]);
```

How to use:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'location', function($scope, location) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    location.skipReload().path(path);
  };
}]);
```

## Old answer

I have written a reusable factory for that based on Jens X Augustsson answer:

```
app.factory('DoNotReloadCurrentTemplate', ['$route', function($route) {
  return function(scope) {
    var lastRoute = $route.current;
    scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
      if (lastRoute.$$route.templateUrl === $route.current.$$route.templateUrl) {
        console.log('DoNotReloadCurrentTemplate',
                    $route.current.$$route.templateUrl);
        $route.current = lastRoute;
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

Works with AngularJS 1.0.6

How to use:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',
  ['$scope', 'DoNotReloadCurrentTemplate',
  function($scope, DoNotReloadCurrentTemplate) {

  DoNotReloadCurrentTemplate($scope);
}]);
```

AngularJS issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699

Comment: is this sort of thing advisable? It sounds like it violates an expectation of the current route design. Are there any side-effects or gotchas to this? Do you expect this to be valid in future releases? You might want to get in touch with the angular team on google plus and get their opinion.

Comment: Well it is a hack... use with caution. What is nice here is that the hackish code does not pollute your controllers, just one line: DoNotReloadCurrentTemplate($scope)

Comment: While the route was not changing I was having a problem with my controller reloading and was able to fix it by modifying `$locationChangeSuccess` to use the `event` and added `event.preventDefault()` on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

define a factory to handle HTML5's window.history like so (note I keep an own Stack to make it work on android as well since it has a few issues there):

```
.factory('History', function($rootScope) {
    var StateQueue = [];
    var StatePointer = 0;
    var State = undefined;
    window.onpopstate = function(){
        // called when back button is pressed
        State = StateQueue.pop();
        State = (State)?State:{};
        StatePointer = (StatePointer)?StatePointer-1:0;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('historyStateChanged', State);
        window.onpopstate = window.onpopstate;

    }
    return {
        replaceState : function(data, title, url) {
            // replace current state
            var State = this.state();
            State = {state : data};
            window.history.replaceState(State,title,url);
            StateQueue[StatePointer] = State;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('historyStateChanged', this.state());
        },
        pushState : function(data, title, url){
            // push state and increase pointer
            var State = this.state();
            State = {state : data};
            window.history.pushState(State,title,url);
            StateQueue.push(State);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('historyStateChanged', this.state());
            StatePointer ++;
        },
        fakePush : function(data, title, url) {
            // call this when you do location.url(url)
            StateQueue.push((StateQueue.length - 1 >= 0)?StateQueue[StateQueue.length -1]:{});
            StatePointer ++;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('historyStateChanged', this.state());
        },
        state : function() {
            // get current state
            return (StateQueue[StatePointer])?StateQueue[StatePointer]:{};
        },
        popState : function(data) {
            // TODO manually popState
        },
        back : function(data) {
            // TODO needed for iphone support since iphone doesnt have a back button
        }
    }
})
```

add a few listeners on your dependent scopes and you will be fine like so:

```
$scope.$on('historyStateChanged', function(e,v) {
        if(v)
            $scope.state = v;
        else
            $scope.state = {}
    });
```

thats how I do it. 
In my point of view the URL should only change when a new view is loaded. 
I think thats how the Angular Team intended it anyways.
If you want to map forward/back button on your model try to do it with HTML5's window.history

Hope I could help.
Cheers, Heinrich

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$routeProvider.when('/somewhere', {
    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

This will prevent reloading the controller on query parameter change, but also on hash change.

Comment: That is not true. It only prevents reload for query params, not hash/route updates. All updates made via $location.path or $location.url go through the $route service triggering a view refresh--hence all the hackish solutions presented on this page to mitigate it.

Comment: ehmicky's solution works fine.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when  "[reloadOnSearch=true] - {boolean=} - reload route when only $location.search() or $location.hash() changes."

Answer (score 1):

If you land here in 2015: The real answer here is to use none of these hacks (I dare name them so, because by using any of the methods listed above you will lose the possibility to use resolve and the likes) but to switch to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

[Here's](http://slides.com/timkindberg/ui-router) a handy presentation on the differences. Implementation should be as simple as swapping $route for $state and converting the states to names.

I'm currently switching over to a method where i will refer with an a href to a route, with an optional get parameter that changes the state without reloading it. For more on this, look at the 'params' section [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution (surprisingly) works for me:

```
$state.params.id = id;  //updating the $state.params somehow prevents reloading the state
$location.path('/articles/' + id);
```

It doesn't prevent the state reloading on Back and forward button though.
Note: I'm using angularjs 1.2.7 and ui-router 0.0.1 (I know it's old).

Answer (score 0):

Here is plugin: https://github.com/anglibs/angular-location-update

Usage:

```
$location.update_path('/notes/1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the `$locationChange~` and `HistoryState` hacks using `route`s [`resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) promise option.

Assuming you had an `article` route where that number is what changed you could do this;

```
$routeProvider.when(
    '/article/:number',
    {
        templateUrl : 'partial.html',
        controller : 'ArticleCtrl',
        resolve : {
            load : ['$q', '$routeParams', function($q, $routeParams) {
                var defer = $q.defer();

                //number was specified in the previous route parameters, means we were already on the article page
                if ($routeParams.number)
                    //so dont reload the view
                    defer.reject('');
                //otherwise, the number argument was missing, we came to this location from another route, load the view
                else
                    defer.resolve();

                return defer.promise;
            }]
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: you would still need to watch for `$locationChangeError` (fired when `defer.reject()` occurs) inside `ArticleCtrl` to make changes to the page based on the now-changed url