# Change route parameters without updating view

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm currently trying to figure out how to change the route parameters without reloading the entire page.  For example, if I start at

http://www.example.com/#/page

but update a name to be 'George', to change the route to be:

http://www.example.com/#/page/george

If I already had http://www.example.com/#/page/:name routed.

Without reloading the location.  Can one just set $routeParams.name = "George" ?

**Edit:**
Alternatively, is there a way to update http://www.example.com/#/page?name=George without reloading or resetting the page?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of searching.  I answered my own question.

I've discovered finding anything on the angular documentation is incredibly impossible, but sometimes, once it's found, it changes how you were thinking about your problem.

I began here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location
Which took me here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location
Which took me to this question: [AngularJS Paging with $location.path but no ngView reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422611/angularjs-paging-with-location-path-but-no-ngview-reload)

What I ended up doing:
I added `$location.search({name: 'George'});` To where I wanted to change the name (A $scope.$watch).

However, this will still reload the page, unless you do what is in that bottom StackOverflow link and add a parameter to the object you pass into `$routeProvider.when`.  In my case, it looked like: `$routeProvider.when('/page', {controller: 'MyCtrl', templateUrl:'path/to/template', reloadOnSearch:false})`.

I hope this saves someone else a headache.

Comment: This solution adds query params and does not replace the existing routeParams, which was your original problem. To replace the existing routeParams you can use `$location.path()` which is a getter and setter.

Comment: Is there any way to update a specific parameter without triggering a refresh using `$location.path()`?

Comment: $location.search() returns an object containing the parameters, update the one you want , and pass it again to $location.search({}).

Comment: hmm, this only works if you're okay with having ?param in your path, but if you just want /param then it looks like you'll need a hack since the Angular team does not seem interested in providing a feature to not reload the page: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699

Answer (score 12):

I actually found a solution that I find a little more elegant for my application.

The $locationChangeSuccess event is a bit of a brute force approach, but I found that checking the path allows us to avoid page reloads when the route path *template* is unchanged, but reloads the page when switching to a different route template:

```
var lastRoute = $route.current;
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
    if (lastRoute.$$route.originalPath === $route.current.$$route.originalPath) {
        $route.current = lastRoute;
    }
});
```

Adding that code to a particular controller makes the reloading more intelligent.

Comment: Beware that the ngRoute module must be explicitly injected in your AngularJS application for this to work.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172558/cannot-inject-routeprovider-in-angular

Answer (score -6):

You can change the display of the page using ng-show and ng-hide, these transitions won't reload the page.  But I think the problem you're trying to solve is you want to be able to bookmark the page, be able to press refresh and get the page you want.

I'd suggest implementing angular ui-router Which is great for switching between states without reloading the page. The only downfall is you have to change all your routes.

[Check it out here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) theres a great demo.