# Angularjs: update location without triggering route

Tags: html, angularjs, routes

I'm creating an image gallery that loads a specific image if it is specified in the route (else loads the first):

```
foo/photos/sports/2
```

Each thumbnail is wrapped in a link to cause the address to change (so users can link back to it directly):

```
<ul class="gallery-thumbnails">
  <li ng-repeat="piece in gallery.pieces">
    <a ng-href="/foo/photos/sports/{{$index+1}}">
      <img ng-src="{{piece.img}}" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that it causes the whole view to be re-rendered instead of just the template binded to the changed scope param (`scope.gallery.selected`).

I can't find a way to cancel the view re-render (but I still want $routeParams to be updated).

I've seen [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14329570) that listen for `$locationChangeSuccess`, but that doesn't work for my scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change route parameters without updating view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981281/change-route-parameters-without-updating-view)

Comment: @stewie, Query params are not appropriate for what I'm doing (I'm creating a URI, not filtering results). I ended up having to switch to ui.router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get close is to use get parameters instead, going to /foo/photos/sports?page={{$index+1}} and in that route (as an argument to "when") set reloadOnSearch: false. You can then update the $location.search (the get parameters) without the page reloading and trigger things on the changes.

```
  // Using reloadOnSearch
  .when('/foo/photos/sports', {
    templateUrl: 'sports',
    reloadOnSearch: false
  });

  // Changing the get parameters (search part of url)
  $location.search({'page': 1});
```

Apart from that I don't think you can do it with the default angular router. It always reloads all controllers on a routechange. You could however switch to another router such as ui-router which I believe can handle reloading parts of a view on path-change.

Comment: Would this work with a link? `<a href="?p=1"><img/></a>` ? I started to look into ui-router, but it's in alpha/beta release :s

Comment: Not sure, I should considering angular intercepts a-tags in general.

Comment: I ended up switching to ui.router. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you navigate directly to `/foo/photos/sports?page={{$index+1}}` it clears the search terms.

Comment: It shouldn't (and doesn't for me). You sure you have nothing else that is removing your params?