# Cannot inject routeProvider in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Could someone please tell me what do I get an error this error AngularJs `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider`

When I run this code

```
    var app = angular.module("app", [])
    .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
                templateUrl : "login.html", 
                controller: "loginController"
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo : "/login"})
  }]);
```

The code is the same (hopefully), as the one on AngularJs official website

Comment: read the manual. It is not available by default in angular core

Comment: I am reading the manual, but where is that file? and why such an important feature is not available by default?

Comment: why? because there are routing alternatives and there are numerous services that aren't in core that require additional files and injection. Can get any file for any version here https://code.angularjs.org/

Comment: thank you, but I have kept getting errors. It turns out that for angular to work better, it needs a webserver as well

Comment: well that's true for all ajax , has nothing to do with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject ngRoute module.

```
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
                templateUrl : "login.html", 
                controller: "loginController"
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo : "/login"})
  }]);
```

and adding angular-route.js on ur page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

and make sure that you are using a web server to run angular

Comment: I got this error after trying your code: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I am getting confused here. is that another file I need to download from angular?

Comment: Yes.. angular-route js don't come with angular js. You need to add it separately.

Answer (score 1):

ngRoute should be injected....

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/login", {
                    templateUrl : "login.html", 
                    controller: "loginController"
                });
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo : "/login"})
      }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also look into using `ui.router` instead. Much more powerful then `ngRoute`. I'm pretty sure the next Angular versions will replace `ngRoute` with `ui.router`.

Comment: It's been over a year since your reply. Did AngularJS replace *ngRoute* with *ui.router* as you predicted or did they go in a different direction?