# Change hash without reloading controller in AngularJS

Tags: url, angularjs, controller

I'm working on a currency converter, and I have url like `#/currency/50/USD/to/EUR`, where 50, USD and EUR are parameters. Now I have a switch function which swaps the currencies and keep the value to convert, I'd like to change the URL as well to something like `#/currency/50/EUR/to/USD` without reloading the controller, just change the hash. I have an idea on how to do with pure js, but is there any solution in angular way?

Comment: You can also look at ui-router module which can replace the standard routing with state base routing and can support your scenario.http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

Comment: @Chandermani thanks for pointing me to `ui-router`!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429133/2104976) out. It sounds just like what you need.

Basically, you seem to have two choices:

1. Listen for `$locationChangeSuccess` event.
2. In your `$routeProvider` definition, while defining the routes and the corresponding templated to load, specify the option `reloadOnSearch = false`.

Comment: Solution one works, but I had to do some tweaks to load other controller when needed.

Answer (score 7):

Ok following callmekatootie solution here's my result, I had to add a condition to be able to go out of my controller when required

```
controller('CurrencyConvertCtrl', function ($scope, $route){
    var lastRoute = $route.current;
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        if($route.current.$$route.controller === 'CurrencyConvertCtrl'){ 
        // Will not load only if my view use the same controller
            $route.current = lastRoute;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: breaks the back button

Comment: I was using something similar which was not changing the route but was reloading the controller. Adding `event.preventDefault()` fixed this for me.