# How to cache state (page) during history back in Angular JS like IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

IONIC has a very good feature to "cache" the state by using ion-nav-view, when user access the state in history, it will not reload the page -- Controller won't be called, and we could enable the cache globally or by page.

While working on a web site, I tend to use Angular JS directly instead of IONIC since IONIC is mainly for the mobile hybrid APP development. However, I really like the way IONIC handle the "history" and page reload.  I know that we could leverage Angular Service to keep page data and achieve the similar function. But I feel it's not convenient to code and we have to put everything into service instead of controller.

Take an example here, we have a pagination search on Page A, by clicking each item to navigate to page B for the detailed item information, if we go back to Page A, we do not want to re-execute the pagination search again. I feel this is a very common requirement for most web site, IONIC's ion-nav-view could achieve this function easily without moving data to service, I wonder is there any angular JS plugins or directive which could help to achieve this function, it's something very similar as what IONIC's ion-nav-view does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for the answer too, no lucky.
One answer is
http://www.tivix.com/blog/dont-forget-the-back-button-in-your-single-page-ap

the author mentioned ngRouter's [reloadOnSearch] option, but i doubt this answer.

From ui-router v0.2.5, there's reloadOnSearch option too, but it's not for our purpose.

another answer is
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2801-revisiting-routing-nested-views-and-caching-with-ngroute-in-angularjs-1-x.htm

I think there's no simple way now, you have to keep controller's status, and restore controller's status on popstate event, and reproduce all controller's actions.
The other way is cache rendered-html, but how can angular touch the restored-html still?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  Seems even the reloadOnSearch doesn't exist yet.  see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636774/angularjs-reloadonsearch-not-working).  I'm convinced to leverage IONIC now since IONIC does provide cached view ability on top of Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$window.history.back()`

Comment: this won't resolve the issue, the controller would still be called and page get reloaded when we call history.back().

Answer (score 0):

History is a consequence of navigation. So I think you are actually asking about AngularJS routing which is responsible for navigation and history management features.  Angularjs has [built-in router](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) but [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) seems to be more main stream because of its additional capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using ui-router, it has extra feature to support multiple ui-views and nested state.  However, I don't think it provide the similar function as IONIC's ion-nav-view,  when the state get switched, it will always call into Controller, it doesn't provide function to "cache" the state.

Comment: Oh I understand. Sorry I missed that in your question. True, there is no rendered view caching in ui-router. It recreates dom and controllers from scratch during transition.  I actually needed it to. Maybe you should modify your question's title and target it for this particular feature.

Comment: I updated the title, hope it could help to clarify my real question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also need the same feature and I found this lib:
http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky

I think It can solve the problem but it make a problem on performance 
because every opened state still working in background and use memory and cpu. (as I think)

**Edit**

ui-router added stiky feature please see this link:
[ui-router/sticky-states](https://github.com/ui-router/sticky-states)

Here how you can use it
**1) Add Plugin**

```
import {StickyStatesPlugin} from "ui-router-sticky-states";

angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']).config(function($uiRouterProvider) {
  $uiRouterProvider.plugin(StickyStatesPlugin);
});
```

**2) Mark a state as sticky**

```
let adminModule = {
  name: 'admin',
  sticky: true,
  views: {
    admin: { component: AdminComponent }
  }
}
```