# Angularjs - Change URL without update current controller and template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm developing a front-end like pinterest, when the pin is clicked this should be loading in a modal, no problem here.

but a requirement is that, the URL should change when the modal is loaded and in the background must keep pins list.

I can't do it, tried using angular-ui, but when the URL change the ui-view elements are cleaned too

Here in stackoverflow are many similar questions, but the problem here is that not children URLs

url1: site.com / list / categorie -> url2: site.com / title

How I can change the URL and keep the current contents in the background?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After few days i got it, this code must be in the controller

```
var lastRoute = $route.current;
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        if($route.current.$$route.controller == 'modal'){
            $route.current = lastRoute;
        }
    });
```

this will keep the current ngview HTML, but change the url

I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429133/1179213

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely use HTML history's API. Check out this post. [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Since you are doing this outside of Angular, it should not affect anything but the URL.

Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks!, i tried this and not work, i use 
history.pushState({}, "page 2", "test.html");
angular take a infinite loop, maybe trying to redirect http://snag.gy/dkJ8e.jpg

Comment: I was implement the code in a loop, my mistake, I will try to implement it in a better way, hope it works, thanks

Comment: I fail to make it work with pushState, is very unstable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query parameter to highlight the correct image using [`$location.search`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) and `$watch`-ers.

Comment: thanks, but this only adds a query string to the end of the url, and the first url is not parent of the second, i think not work in this case