# AngularJS as filter engine

Tags: angularjs, api, url, filter

Can be used AngularJS for the following scenario?

a php back end based on a framework like Laravel or Codeigniter which is used to manage MySQL Data.

On the Frontend AngularJS which shows Data via API (Angular -> <- Codeigniter, Laravel).
The user has the possibility to filter back end data with option Boxes and here is the thing on what I'm not sure about.

On each option I would like to deeplink the result of filtered. How would I do that with angular. I read about routing and I'm not really sure if this would be the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You could try $location.search() to change URL when updating the current filter. And on page load, read the $location.search() and preset the filters. If you are using ngRoute, you may want to set the reloadOnSearch to false for the route which contains the data so that the controller and view aren't recreated when you set the search.

Perhaps the below question and answer could also help
[AngularJS Paging with $location.path but no ngView reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422611/angularjs-paging-with-location-path-but-no-ngview-reload)