# Angular Router not reloading on browser refresh

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the router that comes with Angular 1.3.8.  I've noticed that when a view is loaded and I do a browser refresh, that the controller for that view is not reloaded.  I have to go to another view and then back to get it to reload.  What is the reason for this and is there a way to get it to reload on a refresh?

Thanks.

Router Code:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Grid', {
            templateUrl: "Home/Grid",
            controller: "GridExample",
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .when('/AutoComplete', {
        templateUrl: "Home/AutoComplete",
        controller: "AutoComplete",
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .when('/WebApi', {
        templateUrl: "Home/WebApi",
        controller: "WebapiGridExample",
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .otherwise(
            {
                redirectTo: '/home/Index'
            });
```

Comment: Can you post your router code please

Comment: I've edited to add the router code.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: your urls should not start with capitals.  it just a bad practice.

Comment: How do you know the controller is not being loaded? You doing a console.log() or something similar

Comment: Yes, as well as breaking in the browser (Chrome) debugger.

Comment: Can you post your controller code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for all browsers? because IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox may behave differently. But to address the issue:

You can force a refresh with

```
$route.reload();
```

You can just put that at the beginning of your controller and it should work. Also, these would be good things to read:

[How to watch for a route change in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs)

[AngularJS Paging with $location.path but no ngView reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422611/angularjs-paging-with-location-path-but-no-ngview-reload)

Comment: This does solve the problem as stated (gets me about 3/4 of the way there).  Thanks!