# Angular/Foundation - ng-view inside off-canvas-wrap

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, ng-view

I am having a basic problem, it seems.
The code is pretty simple:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <!-- navigation -->
      <nav class="tab-bar">
        <section class="left-small">
          <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
        </section>
        <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
          <h1 class="title">My App</h1>
        </section>
      </nav>

      <!-- left-hand menu -->
      <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
          <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside>

      <!-- primary content -->
      <div ng-view></div>

      <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
    </div>
  <div>

</body>
```

If I use `ng-view` with the content in a separate file that gets loaded in, it disappears on interaction.  It is there initially, but it disappears after I click the menu icon (*Screenshot 1*).  On refresh the content comes back but further interaction with the off-canvas menu makes it disappear again.

If I take out the `ng-view` element and replace it with static content everything works just fine (*Screenshot 2*).

## Screenshot 1

[image: Screenshot 1]

## Screenshot 2

[image: Screenshot 2]

What am I doing wrong here?

- Angular 1.4.9
- Foundation 5.5.3

Comment: I am assuming because when you click a menu icon, the route is changing, thus the loaded view for that route is changing too.

Comment: I'll have to fiddle around and see if i can prevent navigation on any of those clicks.

Comment: There is this, that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422611/angularjs-paging-with-location-path-but-no-ngview-reload/12429133#12429133

Answer (score 0):

I changed one line to get this working:

This line:

```
<a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

Is now:

```
<span class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></span>
```

I contemplated using `href="javascript:"` but it felt kind of nasty to do that.  However, this works like a charm.  Just note that the inner elements are required to get the actual icon to show up in Foundation 5.  That's why the extra `span` tags are in there.

This wasn't working momentarily due to a typo in my routing configuration.  I was using *tempalte* instead of *template*.

(face palm)