# angular js - Change path but don't reload controller

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I've tried the solution here: https://www.consolelog.io/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/

```
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function (path, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                $route.current = lastRoute;
                un();
            });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
}])
```

But the path I set it to just gets consumed and reverts back to how it was.

Comment: I am skeptical that the monkey parch recommended it that article actually works.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the ngRoute router is to reload the `ngView` when the path changes and the new URL maps to the current route.

If the `reloadOnSearch` option is set to `false`, ngRoute will **not reload the route when** only `$location.search()` or `$location.hash()` changes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/foo", {
        templateUrl: 'foo.html',
        controller: 'fooController',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    });
})
```

And the app invokes:

```
$location.hash({pageNumber: n});
```

A [`$routeUpdate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#event-$routeUpdate) event is broadcast on the root scope (without reloading the route).<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422611/angularjs-paging-with-location-path-but-no-ngview-reload)</sup>