# how to change $routeParams without page reload?

Tags: angularjs

I need to change some URL variables without page reload, I have set the $routeParams's value but this doesn't change in the navigation bar.

Does someone can help me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Change hash and route without completely reloading controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115259/angularjs-change-hash-and-route-without-completely-reloading-controller)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a pure angular way to do this, but [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) allows you to assign urls to states and when you transition between states, it will rewrite the URL without a page reload.