# AngularJS: Problems, when changing hash parameters

Tags: angularjs

I have a AngularJS App. When I have for example following URL:

```
foo.bar/app/#/en
```

and the user change it in the browser to (without reloading the page):

```
foo.bar/app/#/de
```

Some random controllers and $watch-functions are running again, causing some problems.

Is there a way to tell AngularJS not to do anything there? I dont want any functions/controller/whatever to run, if the hash parameter is changed

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14329570/1678067

Works 100% perfect. Still not sure, what is exaclty happening, when I change something in the Hash param (in the URL).