# angular usage of $location in directive repaints all other directives

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that uses several directives:

```
<section class="start_page page--no-vcenter">
        <u-search>
            <u-search-form></u-search-form>
            <u-news-form></u-news-form>
            <u-search-pane></u-search-pane>
        </u-search>
        <u-news>
            <u-news-pane></u-news-pane>
        </u-news>
    </u-search>
</section>
```

When i use a service that uses $location and sets the search() parameters inside of one of the directives all directives repaint.

```
return $location.search(obj);
```

How can avoid this repainting of the other directives?

Im using Angular 1.2.28.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to set the parameters in the url when some filter gets changed inside of the search-form directive: url?foo=baz

Comment: but without repainting the news directive which would cause api calls

Comment: so you change `$location.search()` params in `<u-search-form>` for example but `<u-news-form>` and `<u-search-pane>` also refresh? Do you use `$location` in these sub-directives too?

Comment: yes i use $location in `<u-search-pane>`. i notice that the whole section gets reloaded.

Comment: you can try to assign the `$location` service to a `$scope.location` in `<u-search>` and use only the inherited `location` in all sub-directives (in case you dont use them anywhere else) - so maybe the refresh/event doesn't bubble up globally (so only the actual scope is in the refresh cycle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple since i was only updating the search() part, resp. the query params.

Here you can use

```
$routeProvider.when('/somewhere', {
    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

When changing the path it would be more complicated, i guess.

The issue on github is this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699

And the solution i found in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606908/541949